# Article Content formatting Issue with modules

Tags: joomla, module, article

I faced a strange issue with Joomla default Articles option with custom module.

In joomla article section when I enter some text like 
Price is `$20`  its not displaying on the site front end. When I use with a space `$ 20` It  works fine.

This article is showing on the front end with custom module,

Like this article content is reading from DB using a custom module and out put like

```
echo $fullArticle = JHtml::_('content.prepare', $values->introtext);
```

This module is loading inside another article with `{loadposition mypostion}`

When I put $20 directly in any other article its works fine, I think using custom module and loading position time the Joomla thinks `$20` as a variable or something ?

Please help me to resolve this issue!

Comment: ***cough*** joomla.stackexchange.com ***cough*** :)

Comment: @Lodder there too I'm stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue myself,

I created a content plugin and in that all `$` symbol replaced with `&#36;` I its works!

something like,

```
$article_content = str_replace('$','&#36;',$article->text);
```

Hope this may help someone else in future.